# first install - cms-bolt

Tags: symfony, bolt-cms

I'm installing a new Content Management System (Bolt CMS) which is based on Symfony. I was thrilled by the demo.

I have change the permissions to 777 to the required folders. On accessing the index page, I have the following error. Any idea, guys?

Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Routing\CompiledRoute' not found
File: vendor/symfony/routing/Symfony/Component/Routing/RouteCompiler.php
Line: 67

Thanks very much for your help. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Can you post your directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

In a proper install that file should be located at `vendor/symfony/routing/RouteCompiler.php`.

I am guessing you're installing Bolt as a sub-library of a Composer project that already pulls in Symfony Framework.